# Identifying an array using a string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having difficulties with returning a pre-declared array from user feedback. This is an exercise meant to help me understand how to take user input using a drop-down in HTML and return a value based on a script.

What I want the second part of the script to do is return the array whose name is the string selected by the user.

```
/* This part works in returning the array I need, but it requires that they are placed 
inside an object and returning them based on the key,
which I would want to avoid. */

const obj = { att: [1, 1, 1, 1], btt: [2, 2, 2, 2], ctt: [3, 3, 3, 3], dtt: [4, 4, 4, 4] };
function getOption() {
  let choice = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  function pick(name) {
    return obj[String(name)];
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = pick(choice);
// Drop-down choice "att", output "[1,1,1,1]".
}

/* Here, although the arrays are named One and Two and I return a string that is either
"One" or "Two", JS doesn't seem to notice that those are array names
and returns the string themselves. */

const One = ['a','a'];
const Two = ['b','b'];
function getSecondOption() {
  let choice = document.getElementById("mySelectZwei").value;
  function pick(name) {
    return String(name);
  }
  document.getElementById("demoZwei").innerHTML = pick(choice);
// Drop-down choice "One", output "One".
}
```

I have tried not using String() in the second part but it did not change anything. Array.isArray() doesn't seem to work, either, so it's clear that the editor doesn't see a connection between the array names and the strings.

Would appreciate any feedback telling me what to look into or suggestions for solutions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this? This is one of the primary ways strings are associated to data in JS.

Comment: @DaveNewton The project I am working on will draw on a large number of objects, each with several pairs, and I would like to avoid placing them inside a parent object if possible. Also, I was wondering if it is at all possible to identify an array based solely on its name in string form (I am still learning JS).

Comment: I'm asking why avoid putting them in a "parent object" (or `Map` etc), that's one of the things those data structures are for. There's `eval`, but that is almost always a Really Bad Idea.

Comment: @DaveNewton It would be easier for me to define and handle them independently later in the algo. I wanted to know if there was a better approach than my first solution. Will check out eval, and will keep this structure going forward, am not a fan of Really Bad Approaches. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: It's not clear how handling them would be significantly different later; in either case you're identifying (some data) with a string. Once you have a reference to (the data) where it came from isn't really that important, AFAICT.

Comment: You are trying to access local variables dynamically and that is not possible in JS. Either you need to use `eval` (not recommended) or set it to global scope as `window.one=123` => `wndow[varName]` but this is basically the same as your first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you could use `var` instead of `const` this way variables would not be scoped and attached to the global object `window` and so be accessible using `window[name]`.

try

```js
var One = ['a','a'];
var Two = ['b','b'];
function getSecondOption() {
  let choice = document.getElementById("mySelectZwei").value;
  function pick(name) {
    return window[name];
  }
  document.getElementById("demoZwei").innerHTML = pick(choice);
}
```

Comment: You are not mistaken ;) The issue is the same as w/ all globally-scoped vars, though; the risk of collision is high (particularly if there's a lot of string "identifiers") and in the end, it's just a different parent object.

Comment: @AlexandruMicu I'm happy that it worked but in a way this is close from the 1st solution you proposed